# Is Progress 4gl (Openedge ABL) Able to read STDIN and output to STDOUT?

Tags: linux, progress-4gl, openedge

I need to write a Progress 4gl program to parse input from STDIN so some processing and print the answer back to the screen.

e.g.

cat file_with_text.txt | $DLC/_progres -p .p | grep ...

- Is this possible with the progress 4gl language?
- If not possible with the language, please do not sugest *buy this module from Progress*.  Just tell me it is not possible.
- The version of progress is 10.1b.

I'm begening to think it is not possible.  I will have to convince my managers we need to move away from Progress 4gl.

Comment: It is perfectly possible.  See Tim's answer.

Comment: Try reading/writing to the special files `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stderr`, `/dev/stdout`.  Definitely dump Progress if possible anyway though.  Also your [useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) could be rewritten to `$DLC/_progres < file_with_text.txt | grep ...`

Comment: That is a great idea!  I think that will solve the issue I have.  My example with cat was just to illustrate the what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate:

```
/* cat.p
 *
 */

define variable xline as character no-undo.

do while true:
  import unformatted xline.
  put unformatted xline skip.
end.
```

And then run it like so:

_progres -1 -b -p cat.p < infile > outfile

or (for example):

cat cat.p |  _progres -1 -b -p cat.p | grep unformatted

Answer (score 1):

1) It is possible using progress's "batch processing" mode. Look up "bpro" or "mpro -b"

2) Another possibility to consider is INPUT-OUTPUT THROUGH - this allows Progress to communicate with an external binary, and read it's output back as input. Also, OUTPUT THROUGH would send output to an external program's STDIN.

3) You want to dump Progress as a platform simply because it can't do piped I/O? That's not a good reason to move off a platform to something else which doubtless has other deficiencies relative to Progress.

Comment: I I'm already using bpro/mpro.  The problem INPUT-OUTPU THROUGH is that the communication is initiated by 4gl.  What I need is the 4gl program to be called from a pipe or from another program.   The reason I would like to dump Progress is because is not an open technology that plays well with the rest of the world.  The language is extremely limited. I/O is one of the most basic things you can do in any language, but I haven't seen a single example of it.  Documentation is difficult to find and finding progress developers is almost impossible.

Comment: So use cat some/file/name.txt | mbpro -p progname.p | more - this will work perfectly fine. WRT finding developers - you've got two senior people talking to you now. As for I/O - I'm not sure what you're saying as I do I/O with it all the time. What specifically is the I/O issue you're having?